# Static methods in coffeescript and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I'm fairly new to using coffeescript and I have the following code

```
eventBus = require './eventBus'                      

class Aggregate                                       
  constructor(id) ->                                  
    @_id = id                                         

  @find: (id) ->                                                              
    console.log "Find Called"
    new Aggregate(id)                                                 

  @apply: (event) ->                                                          
    @_total += event.attribute.amount                                         

  @emit: (event) ->                                                           
     EventBus.store event                                                     

module.Aggregate = Aggregate
```

The problem I have is I want to call Aggregate.find 20 
which in turn will return a new aggregate with that ID. Any advice on how to get this module to work like this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers Mike.

Comment: PS: `new @(id)` does The Right Thing inside a class method: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/2snz3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work fine, except that you have a syntax error in your constructor.

Change:

```
constructor(id) ->
```

to:

```
constructor: (id) ->
```

Answer (score 0):

Append this somewhere:

```
Aggregate.find = (id) ->                                                              
  console.log "Find Called"
  new Aggregate(id)
```

And it would be "static" method.

Comment: Using `@` in a class context does this, so his `find` method is already in the right place.